# Return value of last non blank cell in 3D range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm working on a workbook that tracks monthly numbers, and also provides a yearly and quarterly summary for those months. The workbook has a Fiscal Year sheet, four quarterly sheets (named Q1-Q4), and 12 sheets for the months (Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, etc). All of sheets in this workbook look identical.

Completing most of the Fiscal Year sheet is fairly simple, just use the formula `=SUM(Jul:Jun!B3)`, which looks at all 12 monthly sheets and sums cell "B3". No problems there.

However, we have a backlog section that shows how far behind we are. For this number on the Fiscal Year sheet, I just want the number from the latest month of data. Since it's not a cumulative sum of all the months before, it's causing me issues.

I need a formula that will find the last non-blank cell in those 12 monthly sheets (they are in fiscal year order), and return just that cells value. The range for that formula would be `Jul:Jun!B17`. So if March is the last months worth of data, and the backlog number for march is `56`, I want `56` to show on my Fiscal Year sheet.

I tried using

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/('Jul:Jun'!B17<>""),B17)
```

But it becomes this

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/('Jul:[June]June'!B17<>""),B17)
```

And returns a `#REF!` error. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `Jul:Jun!B17` supposed to mean? What is your worksheet name and what is the full range that you are trying to find the last non-blank cell?

Comment: Jul:Jun!B17 is the full range that I'm trying to find the last non-blank cell. It's July through June (fiscal year). I need a formula that will look at cell B17 over every month (July is the first month, June is the last month) and return the value of the last non-blank cell? The sheet I'm trying to put the formula in is named "Fiscal Year", and the formula would go in cell B17 on that sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question correctly, then the following Array formula will give you what you seek: =INDEX(A1:A16,MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A16),ROW(A1:A16),""))).This can be put in A17 for July and copied across the row to L17 for June.

Comment: Roger, thanks for this reply. I do the report once a month, so I'm just now getting back to it. I think you might be misunderstanding my question a bit. I'm editing my original post to be more clear as well. I have 12 sheets, named Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, etc. Each sheet has it's months data. I also have a Fiscal Year sheet that adds all the months data together. All of the sheets look exactly the same. I need a formula that will look at all 12 individual month sheets, find the last sheet with data in cell B17, and show that data on my Fiscal Year sheet. I hope that makes this a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh,I see.The following formula is a bit cumbersome, but solves what you are trying to accomplish.I would imagine that using VBA would be more direct and simpler, but in your example of effort you used formulas so I take it that you prefer a formulaic answer :

=CHOOSE(MAX(IF(Sheet1!B17>0,1,0),IF(Sheet2!B17>0,2,0),IF(Sheet3!B17>0,3,0),IF(Sheet4!B17>0,4,0),IF(Sheet5!B17>0,5,0),IF(Sheet6!B17>0,6,0),IF(Sheet7!B17>0,7,0),IF(Sheet8!B17>0,8,0),IF(Sheet9!B17>0,9,0),IF(Sheet10!B17>0,10,0),IF(Sheet11!B17>0,11,0),IF(Sheet12!B17>0,12,0)),Sheet1!B17,Sheet2!B17,Sheet3!B17,Sheet4!B17,Sheet5!B17,Sheet6!B17,Sheet7!B17,Sheet8!B17,Sheet9!B17,Sheet10!B17,Sheet11!B17,Sheet12!B17)

Comment: @ user4907546 : Of course your actual sheet names will be different from my formula's sheet names ... Sheet1!B17  will be "Jul!B17" , Sheet2!B17 will be "Aug!B17" ...etc.